# image handler not working iis 7 integrated mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am moving website from one server to another both being IIS 7.
It has handler which is used to serve images.And now after migrating, 
the handler just refuses to work.I am running in integrated mode
in iis 7 and setting seem to exactly same as old server.
Can anyone give any clues on how can i possibly check the problem?

the image does not render and only shows name of handler.

Comment: Can you paste the part of your web.config where you register your image handler?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you actually have the correct MIME type added for your file type.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your web.config's handler sections match between the two servers. IIS7 normally does an OK job of surfacing most web.config settings but there could be a minor difference between the two systems preventing the handler from being picked up for the request.

Here's a link on how to [register](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  a HTTP Handler in a web.config file. Jump down to the integrated mode section.